# Change browser tester in Travis-CI

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, travis-ci

Is there some alternative browser testing that I can add via yml?
I am using PhantomJS 1.9.2 but the results are a bit weird and don't show up in "real browsers"...

EDIT: seems to be a [**open issue**](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10832) about this bug. One more reason for this question...

Any pointer?

I am using **GruntJS**:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){  
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-html-spec-runner');   
    grunt.initConfig({
        connect: {
            testServerHeadless: {
                options: {port: 9001}
            },
            testServer: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    keepalive: true
                }
            }
        },
        jasmine: {
            core15: {
                src: ['http://localhost:9001/myTestsHere...']
            }
        }
    });   
    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'connect:testServerHeadless',
        'jasmine:core15'
    ]);    
};
```

And my **yml**:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be glad if you can be more explicit about your issue.
Do you have an error? What do you mean by "weird"?

In the meantime, I was checking the documentation of `grunt-jasmine`, and I stepped on that:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine#optionshost

Apparently, if you want to run PhantomJS against a Jasmine testing page, you have to use the property `host` instead of `src`.
If not, Grunt will try to find the sources on the local file system which might be... weird.

I am doing a lot of assumptions here but maybe it's a good place to start?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! The problem seems to be that javascript `setTimeout` behaves wrong in Phantom. That is clear on the github issue I posted, also clear [here](https://travis-ci.org/mootools/mootools-core) where all the setTimeout code checks crash.

Comment: Any suggestions/questions after my comment?

Comment: Did you try the ugly fix a guy is proposing at the end of the Git issue you referenced (By any chance): https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10832#issuecomment-30869416

Comment: My wish is to test a framework, so adding dozens of setTimeout patches, changing the original code, is not a option.

Comment: Auélien, any new ideas about this?